# How can we know all typesets used by a Latex document?

Tags: typography, latex-to-word

I have used Latex for many years and saw a lot of benefits from using it but, for some reason, I need to work on a shared word processor form with my research group (they prefer working with this platform to overleaf).

I would like to know the way to extract all typesetting (fonts, sizes, margins, indents, line spacing, etc.) used by a Latex document format, e.g. Revtex4-1, so that I can make my word processor format as similar as the Latex format as possible.

Comment: for fonts you can use the pdffonts program or font menu in your pdf viewer which will list the fonts used. for margins and spacing you need to look at the revtex source or simply measure the printed document,

Comment: Some PDF viewers can list all fonts used and even extract them. For example, the default PDF viewer for KDE, Okular, has a font tab in the file properties dialog.
If you are using the default latex fonts, you will want to use Latin Modern in word, instead of Computer Modern, partly because of issues with math.

Answer (score 1):

For the general layout parameters (margins, header/footers etc) use the `layouts` package. For instance:

```
% layoutsprob.tex  SE 546636

\documentclass{report} % or whatever your class is
\usepackage{layouts}
%%%% make changes to the layout (via geometry?)

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\oddpagelayoutfalse
\twocolumnlayouttrue
\pagediagram
\caption{Left-hand two-column page layout parameters}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\currentpage
\oddpagelayouttrue
\pagedesign
\caption{Odd page layout for this document}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which will produce two figures, one showing the page layout controls for a particular page, and the other a brief diagram of a particular page layout plus a tabulation of the specific values of the layout controls.

The [`layouts` package](//texdoc.net/pkg/layouts) provides many facilities including trying out experimental page designs.

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with a command-line `texdoc <package>` reference. My suggestion would be to provide a clickable URL: `[<package> package](//texdoc.net/pkg/<package>)` like I did at the end of your post. It's a convenience provided to the OP, I know.

Comment: @Werner I tried your "clickable URL" with the result that nothing was found.

Comment: Okay, that was lame on my part. URL should be `//texdoc.net/pkg/<package>`, not `//texdoc.net/pks/<package>`. I've fixed it.

Comment: @Werner the `texdoc package` is the default mechanism for reading LaTeX documentation. Perhaps everyone should be familiar with it. If nobody mentioned it then would it ever get used?

Comment: I think very few people use a command-line interface to negotiate compilation and/or documentation viewing. They mostly rely on what is provided through their IDE and search for documentation online (via texdoc.net). My suggestion is more along the lines of spoon-feeding the audience so their needs could be met with a single click, rather than a terminal, some typing and ENTER. I understand... your opinion may differ. You can always roll back my edit.